# Is there a standard way to write this tightly coupled for loop so that it doesn't burn up 100 percent of my CPU

Tags: multithreading, go

I'm pretty new to Go, but I've been enjoying it so far. I have this one piece of code that burns up quite a bit of my CPU and I was wondering if there was a more Go oriented idiomatic way to write such a loop. I think such a loop would be common so there should be a better way to write this, maybe using Go's sync package.

The loop functionally looks something like this. Given that `es.SomeCondition` is being manipulated by other threads...

```
type ExampleStruct struct {
    SomeCondition        bool
    mu                   sync.Mutex
}

func (es *ExampleStruct) runTimeOut() int {
    timeout := 800
    segmentOfSleep := 20
    timeSleep := currentTimeout/segmentsOfSleep
    for i := 0; i < segmentsOfSleep; i++ {
        es.mu.Lock()
        if es.SomeCondition == true {
            return 1
        }
        es.mu.Unlock()
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(timeSleep) * time.Millisecond)
    }
    return 0
}
```

The above code eats up my CPU and I can see why but I can't think of a solution.

Anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: I think you can just use a signal channel directly from other threads that are updating SomeCondition

Comment: Do not busy wait.  Use [sync.Cond](https://godoc.org/sync#Cond) or maybe a channel.  There's not enough information in the question to recommend the best approach.

Comment: I don't think "tightly coupled" means what you think it means. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)